# How to adjust bandwidth for ridgeplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

When using the `geom_density_ridges` function in the `ggridges` package, it always picks a bandwidth for all the densities in the plot. But is there a way to adjust the bandwidth that it chooses?

I currently have some code to make a ridge plot, but the bandwidth is too low for the bottom density. I would like to adjust it so that it is smoother and less rough.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
hier_plot <- ggplot(hier_df, aes(x=x, y=as.factor(beta), fill = factor(beta))) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#fffffC")) +
  labs(y = expression(beta), x = 'x', expression(beta), fill = expression(beta)) +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 2.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.05, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Reds')

hier_plot
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty sure you can just add it as an argument to `geom_density_ridges()` *e.g.*

```
+ geom_density_ridges(bandwidth = 0.1)
```

The argument is passed to the underlying function `stat_density_ridges`.

Comment: How would you choose an appropriate banwidth?

Comment: @dzegpi I have come across a method for that once, called the "plug-in" method (Wand, 1995). I haven't read the paper neither did I read papers mentioning this technique, but a quick google scholar search will bring up some. Anyway, this method (up to you to decide if you deem it suitable to your data) is implemented in the KernSmooth package in R with the function 'dpih'.